# Does Naruto have the potential to be as powerful as Kaguya Ōtsutsuki?

Tags: naruto

In [Chapter 692: Revolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOHZx.jpg), Hagoromo said to Naruto that

> Even with the chakra of all the tailed beasts, you won't become like she did. Whatever the case maybe, you are different than my mother

I don't understand why Hagoromo gave Kaguya's example. He himself was a Jinchuriki, he was also powerful but it didn't corrupt him. With the tailed beasts inside him, does Naruto have the potential to be the strongest, surpassing even Hagoromo ?

Comment: The answers is **yes**.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Can you elaborate? I have not been following Naruto for quite some time now, forgot almost all the details.

Comment: **Yes** (coz the question is answerable by yes or no) But to elaborate the answer is merely opinion-based.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru I would love to here opinions.

Comment: But stackexchange sites prefer questions with definite answers, not opinion based questions.

Comment: Actually there is a definite answer to this question, if i may be allowed to answer?